# Connect to MariaDB using TLS without certificate files

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

Im currently trying to connect to my MariaDB and Insert data into it. I want the connection between clients and my server to be encrypted. I already did make TLS work on server side,  [as explained here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-secure-connections-to-mariadb-with-ssl-encryption_595079). 
What I want is for clients to connect to MariaDB without certificate files.
My current `ConnectionString` is:

`$@"Data Source ={ hostName }; Initial Catalog = usersInfo; User ID = user; Password = password; SslMode=Required;"`

But it doesnt connect I guess because it also needs the cert files.

config file `50-server.cnf` contains:

```
#ssl = on
ssl
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem

[mariadb]
ssl
```

config file `50-client.cnf` contains:

```
[client-mariadb]
ssl
```

Comment: a certificate on the client side would only be neccessary if you want to authenticate your client. As for having an encrypted connection, look [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/secure-connections-overview/). Also are you sure you want SSL and not TLS?

Comment: I guess I need TLS, edited the Q

Comment: "But it doesnt connect I guess because it also needs the cert files." No, server certificate files aren't necessary to use TLS to connect to MariaDB/MySQL. Can you post the full error message and exception call stack? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I fixed it. The problem was I installed MariaDB from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS default repository and it was version 10.1 with static yaSSL library. I updated [this] (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-deb-files/) and now I have 10.4.10 with dynamic OpenSSL 1.1.1. Its fixed the issue. And I defined `tls_version=TLSv1.0,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` for both mariadb and client-mariadb aswell and now its fixed without needing cert files.